# how to load first n rows from a scv file with phpexcel?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-io, phpexcel

I haven't seen an example on loading the first `n` rows from afile

So far I have:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_name);
$sheetData   = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(NULL, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE);
```

The reason I want to load only a few rows is that my file is large (10.000 entries) and im thinking that loading a few rows will be faster.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ***load*** only a few rows, then use a read filter (as described in section 5.3 of the [reader documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Reading%20Spreadsheet%20Files), entitled `Reading Only Specific Columns and Rows from a File (Read Filters)`).

If you've already loaded the file and only want to extract a few rows as an array into $sheetdata, then use `rangeToArray()` instead of `toArray()`

Comment: witch method you think is the fastest. loading the  file then iterating and inserting into the database or using the reader for the same thing?

Comment: I can't possibly say which is the fastest, because it's all dependent on your spreadsheet file, and what you want to extract from it.... but it's also better to iterate over the worksheet rows inserting each in turn rather than transferring the worksheet into an array and then iterating over the array

Comment: @Mark Baker if you could also provide the link to "the reader documentation" (as SO always recommends), that would be much more helpful... because that whole github navigation and searching for documentation is very hard... Thanks